# WCF Gzip on POST Request

Tags: wcf, http-post, gzip

I have a WCF service with some post requests. I am using JSON for this WCF. Through the client for the WCF i need to send a GZipped/Compressed content to that POST method. How to achieve this?

Comment: It will be helpful if you post what you have already tried and where it failed exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GZipStream class from System.IO.Compression namespace to compress your request data. Following sample code shows how you can compress it.

```
using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
      using(var zipStream = new GZipStream(requestStream , CompressionMode.Compress))
      {
           zipStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);         
      }
}
```